# adding Char or NSString into Objective C enum

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, nsdictionary

I have created an enum in my header file that looks like this

```
typedef enum {stTMD = 1, stT2MD = 2, stDCMD = 'D', stMBMD = 'M'} stTypes;
```

First off I am not even sure if thats the correct way to declare a char in an enum but
As you can see some values are integers and others are chars. However I am getting the following error when I try to place these values into a NSDicitonary like this

```
NSDictionary *iCTypes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:stDCMD,@"stMB", stMBMD,@"stMBMD", nil];
```

but I am getting this error below

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A char value will be between 0 and 255. You cannot use either a string or an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` is basically an `int` type. Your `enum` definition is just fine. The problem is your use in the dictionary. You need to wrap the `enum` values in an `NSNumber`.

Try:

```
NSDictionary *iCTypes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:stDCMD], @"stMB", [NSNumber numberWithInt:stMBMD] ,@"stMBMD", nil];
```

or even better (using modern Objective-C):

```
NSDictionary *icTypes = @{ @(stDCMD) : @"stMB", @(stMBMD) : @"stMBMD" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store objects inside it, so you can't store an *int*, rather a *NSNumber*, which can be made by appending a *@* before the number constant:

```
NSDictionary *iCTypes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @(stDCMD),@"stMB", @(stMBMD),@"stMBMD", nil];
```

However a clarification is needed on this:

> First off I am not even sure if thats the correct way to declare a char in an enum but As you can see some values are integers and others are chars.

When you define an enum it stores integers, it doesn't matter if you set chars as values, they're compatible with *int* so the compiler will not complain. But the storage type is the same, they're still integers and any type compatible with integers will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Both the objects and keys in an NSDictionary must be objects, and the keys specifically must be objects that conform to NSCopying. In order to use ints in an NSDictionary, you have to convert them to NSNumbers. You can use either `[NSNumber numberWithInt:stDCMD]` or, if you're using a newer version of Xcode, `@(stDCMD)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C char is a kind of short int. 
enum can only hold integer types. 
NSDictionary cannot hold C types. Only objects. 
You can wrap your C types in NSValue or NSNumber to put in an NSDictionary.